# XMLHTTPRequest cross-server request for IE7 and under

Tags: internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I need send request from **1.abc.com/test.html** to **2.abc.com/target.jsp**
It works fine under IE8, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

For IE8 I use XDomainRequest and for other browsers I use XMLHttpRequest. But for IE7 neither works. However, I believe there is a way for IE7 since source page and target page are under same domain **abc.com** even though I don't know how. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: **1.abc.com** and **2.abc.com** *are* two different domains. In fact even making a request from **abc.com** to any of its sub-domains counts as cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveXObject `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` and `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` (if it's on the same domain).

You should read [this](http://www2007.org/papers/paper801.pdf) if you wanna do cross-subdomain requests. As an alternative you could use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which **circumvents JavaScript's same-source policy**.

Comment: This answer contains false information. JSON has nothing to do with the same-origin policy and cannot circumvent it. You might mean *JSON-P*, which is nothing else than including a script element in the page (same-origin policy does not apply to script elements).